# Reset FormArray to initial state

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a `FormArray` with some initial controls in it. The user has an option to add controls by clicking a button which triggers the [push()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#push) method.

I wanna give the user a cancel button which will reset the form to its initial state, removing all added controls.

As of now I am thinking of two approaches:

**Option 1**:
keep track of the index where the controls were added and use the [removeAt()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#removeat) method

**Option 2**: alternatively, I can just reconstruct the entire `FormArray` with its initial config.

But is there a simpler way to reset the FormArray to a certain state, something like when we reset the value using [setValue()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#setvalue) or I have to rebuild it manually using the above options?

Comment: What have you tried post your code here or stackblitz example.

Comment: Clarified the question

Comment: Lemme add a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear all form array values you can use `.clear()`

here is the complete code will all possible methods (`add`, `remove`, `reset`)

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

get skills() {
  return this.form.get('skills') as FormArray;
}

newSkill(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
   skill: '',
   exp: '',
 })
}

addSkill() {
  this.skills.push(this.newSkill());
}

removeSkill(index) {
  this.skills.removeAt(index);
}

resetSkill() {
 this.skills.clear();
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
   name: [''],
   email: [''],
   skills: this.fb.array([])
 });
}
```

Template

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  Name <input type="text" formControlName="name"> <br>
  Email <input type="text" formControlName="email"> <br>
  <div formArrayName="skills">
   <div *ngFor="let skill of skills.controls; let i=index">
     <div [formGroupName]="i">
       skill name :
       <input type="text" formControlName="skill">
       exp:
       <input type="text" formControlName="exp">

       <button (click)="removeSkill(i)">Remove</button>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="addSkill()">Add Skill</button>

  <br><br>
  <button type="button" (click)="resetSkill()">Reset Skills</button>
</form>
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wzgfck)

Comment: Thanks but it does not answer my question :(  The clear method clears the entire array. I am looking to reset the array to a previous state.

Comment: @emmbee checkout stackblitz I have update now it will reset with previous state, lemme know if it works for you.

Comment: Ok but that's basically option 2 from the question... I'll accept the answer as I don't think there is a better way to do it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @emmbee thanks you can upvote the answer it would help others.